# Deploy API that saves images on file system

Tags: spring-boot, image, api, file, filesystems

I‘m working on a personal project with friends that is like a site/app to register your pets, when the user register a pet there’s a picture of the pet that is saved on the file system of the project. If I deploy this API on heroku (for example) will the image saving part work? I have never deployed anything and I don’t know how it works, specially with file system

Nothing, I’m learning

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I was recently in a very similar situation, but opted to only have owners register a URL to an image (which I could then easily display without needing big storage). Could that be an option, that eliminates the question?